# Why my code don't work when it should?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

problem is when i want to write something in textbox i can't focus on it.
thanks for cooperate:)

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Hello Phone" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Name="MessageTextBox" 
                 FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Margin="20,20,10,20" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="ClickMeButton" Content="Click Me" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="4" Margin="10,20,20,20" Click="ClickMeButton_Click" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Name="BannerTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" 
           Foreground="#FFFF7A00" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Comment: I ask my self the same thing everyday.

Comment: Use a better subject line.  The subject should describe more specifically what the question is about.  "Please help me" titles help no one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the property "IsEnabled" to true.

**EDIT:** I actually tried it and it doesn't look like it works. Strangely enough if you call *Focus()* on it from the code behind it works.

**EDIT:** Figured it out! You need to set proper "RowDefintions" on your Grid. Check out this code:

```
<!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Hello Phone" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="MessageTextBox" Margin="20,20,10,20" IsEnabled="True" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="ClickMeButton" Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="4" Margin="10,20,20,20" Click="ClickMeButton_Click" IsEnabled="True" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Name="BannerTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"            Foreground="#FFFF7A00" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"           TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) but i don't understand why i need  to set 2 times same proper"RowDefinitions"? it's strange for me but it's work ;)

Comment: @harry180 Well before you can take advantage of a row you first have to create a RowDefinition for it. So I created 2 rowdefintions, one for the textbox and button, and one for the Textblock located underneath it.

Comment: oh i see now everything is clear :) thanks again:) question can be closed:)